# Get json value without string prefix

Tags: javascript, json, xpath

I have a json like this:

> var x = {"foo:bar":"xyz"};

I can get xyz by call x["foo:bar"] but is there anyway to get xzy by calling just bar and remove the foo prefix? something like x["bar"]? The json is converted from xml with namespace like that, I can't change it. Thanks

Comment: create your JSON so that the key is only `bar`.

Comment: What does "just def" mean?  Who creates the json - do you? If it's you, just follow @JustinWood advice and modify how you output it.

Comment: The json is converted from xml with namespace like that, I can't change it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the property names and remove the prefix:

```
function removePrefix(x){
    var temp = {};
    for(var key in x){
        temp[key.substr(key.indexOf(':')+1)] = x[key];
    }
    return temp;
}

var x = {"foo:bar":"xyz"};

x = removePrefix(x);

console.log( x['bar'] ); // xzy
console.log( x.bar ); // xyz
```

Comment: what if the structure of the json is more complex, eg: it has child and array in it?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a JSON string which would look like this:

```
var x = {"foo":"xyz"};
```

your current key: `"foo:bar"` does not have any special meaning in JSON, it's part of the key.